# How to reset everything in my javascript game

Tags: javascript

I built an extensive minesweeper game in JS and I'm trying to implement an effective way to restart the game on click but I'm coming up short. Right now I'm just making the entire page reload on click but that's not what I want to happen. The way I built the game, everything is placed on load, so I'm not sure how to approach this without refactoring all of my code. I tried creating a function that resets all global variables, removes all the divs I created before and then calls a function which I created to just wrap all my code and do it all over again. This approach removed the divs but did not place them again.

This is my primary function

```
function createBoard() {

  const bombsArray = Array(bombAmount).fill('bomb')
  const emptyArray = Array(width * height - bombAmount).fill('valid')
  const gameArray = emptyArray.concat(bombsArray)

  //  --Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm--
  const getRandomValue = (i, N) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (N - i) + i)
  gameArray.forEach((elem, i, arr, j = getRandomValue(i, arr.length)) => [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]])

  // --- create squares ---
  for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.setAttribute('id', i)
    square.classList.add(gameArray[i])
    grid.appendChild(square)
    squares.push(square)

    square.addEventListener('click', function () {
      click(square)
    })

    square.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      addFlag(square)
    }
  }

  //add numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    let total = 0
    const isLeftEdge = (i % width === 0)
    const isRightEdge = (i % width === width - 1)

    if (squares[i].classList.contains('valid')) {
      //left
      if (i > 0 && !isLeftEdge && squares[i - 1].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //top right
      if (i > 9 && !isRightEdge && squares[i + 1 - width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //top 
      if (i > 10 && squares[i - width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //top left 
      if (i > 11 && !isLeftEdge && squares[i - 1 - width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //right 
      if (i < 129 && !isRightEdge && squares[i + 1].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //bottom left 
      if (i < 120 && !isLeftEdge && squares[i - 1 + width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //bottom right
      if (i < 119 && !isRightEdge && squares[i + 1 + width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++
      //bottom 
      if (i <= 119 && squares[i + width].classList.contains('bomb')) total++

      squares[i].setAttribute('data', total)
    }
  }
}
createBoard()
```

Really I just want to be able to clear on click the divs this function creates and then make them again. When I try this:

```
function resetGame() {
  width = 10
  height = 13
  bombAmount = 20
  squares = []
  isGameOver = false
  flags = 0
  grid.remove('div')
  createBoard() 
}
```

This effectively removes the grid squares created on load but it doesn't create them again. I want to be able to run that initial function again. How can I do that?

Here's a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-river-r1fef?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: You probably want to steer towards a more object-oriented approach with a `class` that represents your game state. Then you can do `new Board()` instead of messing around with all these disassociated variables.

Comment: This is a parcel issue, see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602686/javascript-function-wont-trigger-when-called-in-html-file-during-parcel-build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript function won't trigger when called in HTML file during Parcel build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602686/javascript-function-wont-trigger-when-called-in-html-file-during-parcel-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the `.grid` container, instead of

```
grid.remove("div");
```

Use the following statement to remove all content of the container

```
grid.innerHTML = "";
```

[Pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-water-q7ek5?file=/src/index.js:6580-6600)